# Defining a particular strategy of ID generation in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, primary-key

how i can define and use a strategy of ID (primary keys) generation for my domain classes ? I want to put a prefix  for the primaryKey of some domain classes like customers and manufacturers based in the ID (primary key) of their hometown. I know that Hibenate has a API for this, but who i can integrate such strategy in my Grails application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Grails User Documentation shows how to create a custom ID generator under the [Database Mapping Section > ID](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html) .